# Can't connect Java and MySQL on docker

Tags: java, mysql, docker, docker-compose

When I run the docker compose, it returns the error

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
> refused)

I don't have much experience with docker.. what am i doing wrong?

My docker compose:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - phonebook-network
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=PhoneBook

    restart: on-failure

  phonebook-service:
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        JAR_FILE: ./Phonebook-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=jdbc:mysql://mysql-service:3306/PhoneBook?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false
      - DB_USERNAME:admin
      - DB_PASSWORD:admin
    networks:
      - phonebook-network
    depends_on:
      - mysql-service

    restart: on-failure

networks:
  phonebook-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
VOLUME /phoneBook
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Could you show the address to which you're trying to connect MySQL from your java container?

Comment: Is the application starting up before the database is ready?  (If you run `docker-compose up` without a `-d` option, do you see database logs showing up after the application container has failed?)

Comment: yes, its jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PhoneBook?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: the "depends_on" config dont resolve the problem about the order that the containers start?

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure the ports are exposed in MySQL as well:

```
services:
  mysql-service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - phonebook-network
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=PhoneBook

    restart: on-failure
```

---

> the "depends_on" config dont resolve the problem about the order that the containers start?

Yes, the `depends_on` ensures that the MySQL container will start before the Java one, but it might happen that MySQL itself takes a long time to bootstrap, so the container is ready but the process inside is not.

---

If the problem still persists, this can be a possible solution: create a `docker_entrypoint.sh` file at the root of your project. This also assumes the container has `netcat` installed.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Waiting for MySQL..."

# I'm assuming you're running it in a default port (3306)
until nc -vz "mysql-service" 3306; do
  >&2 echo "Waiting for MySQL to be available..."
  sleep 0.1
done

echo "MySQL started"

java -jar /app.jar
```

then modify your Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
VOLUME /phoneBook
ARG JAR_FILE

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends netcat \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
COPY ./docker_entrypoint.sh docker_entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 100 docker_entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT [ "./docker_entrypoint.sh" ]
```

I don't have a way to test this right now, but let me know if this works.

Comment: it causes the error standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error

Comment: i forgot to put #!/bin/bash on sh file. then it just print  ./docker_entrypoint.sh: line 4: nc: command not found
phonebook-service_1  | Waiting for MySQL to be available...

Comment: The container needs to have `netcat` installed, I was not sure if that `openjdk` image used `debian` or not. Edited to install the missing dep.